# SHL numerical reasoning question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi I've screen shot the question and attached it here. I have tried numerous methods to solve it but can't seem to get an answer which correlates to one of the choices given. So i need help on working it out please..Thanks![image]

Comment: I multiplied the original profit by the maximum production which is 2.50 x 210 and got 525.then for the new production method I did 6.3 which is the new profit multiplied by 250 which is the new maximum production and i got 1575. then i did the percentage increase method 1575-525=1050 then 1050/1575 * 100= 66%.. that's what i did and got!

Comment: Shouldn't you divide by the the original profit? Because you want to know the amount it's increased from the original: $(1575-525)/525 = 2$, so the percentage increase is $200\%$

Comment: Yes thank you... what a stupid mistake haha!

Comment: Shl test as homework? Is the assignment to land yourself a job?

Comment: yes! this is my assignment right now :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Original profit** 
2.50 x 210 = 525

**New Profit**
6.3 x 250 = 1575

**Percentage Increase**
1575-525 = 1050
1050/525*100 = 200

**Answer**
Answer is 200%

Thanks to @andraiamatrix!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply on a dead/dying post. Surely isn't the answer c? 252%

I agree with part of your method but I think you're missing out crucial information.

Original Profit = 2.5 x 210 = 525

New Profit      = 6.3 x 250 = 1575

**Agreed.**

But using these figures alone assumes they have they same initial turnover which clearly can't be the case since you are producing more units with the second method, therefore, increasing your turnover and altering your % profit.

Original Turnover = 12.5 x 210 = 2625

New Turnover      = 12.5 x 250 = 3125

**Profit as a %:**

Original profit = 525/2625 * 100 = 20%

New Profit      = 1575/3125 * 100 = 50.4%

Therefore, the company would see profits increase from 20% to 50.4% which is:

50.4/20 * 100 = 252% increase in profit.

Answer: C, 252%

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit of a late reply also. I'm practicing my numerical skills as I have an SHL test for placement next week >.<

Anyways, the answer is 200%.

Original profit before changes to labour costs:

```
12.50 - (7.25+2.65+0.10) = $2.50
```

This is profit. You multiply this by `210` since `$2.50` is the profit of one unit and the company makes 210 units a month. HENCE the monthly profit is $525.

Profit after changes to labour costs:

`12.50 - (3.45+2.65+0.10) = $6.30 <- Profit of one unit. The company makes 250 units now HENCE profit is

```
$6.30 * 250 = $1575
```

Now its as simple as calculating the percentage increase between the 2 profits:
((1575-525)/525)*100 = 200%

Answer (score 0):

Original Profit - $\$2.5$

New Profit - $(7.25-3.45)+2.5 = 6.3$

The question says % increase in Profit for Product C

Increase in Profit % = $6.3/2.5 = 252%$